# How to create a "Quiz" model that has unknown number of options with one or more correct answers?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a model for a "Question/Quiz" . A question can have as many choices (Charfields) as user wants , and there can be one or many correct answers (out of those options) . How should I define this model?﻿

Question: Some long description.

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3  - Correct Ans
- Choice 4  - Correct Ans

So far I came up with this but I think it is a bad design:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=300)
    correct_answer_id = models.UUIDField('answer_id', null=True)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)

class Answer(models.Model):
    """
    Answer's Model, which is used as the answer in Question Model
    """
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=u'Answer\'s text')
    ans_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid1())
```

Comment: if you have multiple correct answers, `Answer` should have a `correct`-flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555845/daniel), you should provide your answers with a correct-flag. Also, it seems more sensible to give them a fk to `Question` as multiple questions fitting the same answer is odd. This way one answer always belongs to a single question:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=300)

    def correct_answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.filter(correct=True)

    # ...


class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    correct = models.BooleanField('Correct', default=False)
```

Comment: When I set the above, and I try to migrate, it tells me , "non-nullable field 'question' to answer without a default"

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have a data model like: quiz has one-to-many questions, and questions have one-to-many answers (of which multiple can be correct).

So I'd do something like:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
  ...
class Question(models.Model):
  quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
  ...
class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  text = ...
  is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then most of the details would be based on how you query to build the "survey"/ quiz and grade it.